# muenchian grouping to create node from xsl key

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

Using xsl key to parse some unique entries and creating new nodes with the key values in the key.

The following xml:

```
<Services>
        <Service Name="Publish" TypeName="FzUDP.Publish" ProviderName="FzUDP" Position="69,102.533530201483" InitPriority="1">
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastIp" Value="224.0.0.0" />
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastPort" Value="61499" />
          <Parameter Name="Encryption" Value="0" />
          <Parameter Name="PacketFormat" Value="0" />
        </Service>
        <Service Name="Subscribe" TypeName="FzUDP.Subscribe" ProviderName="FzUDP_1" Position="547,107.533530201483" InitPriority="2">
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastIp" Value="224.0.0.0" />
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastPort" Value="61499" />
          <Parameter Name="Decryption" Value="0" />
          <Parameter Name="PacketFormat" Value="0" />
        </Service>
<Service Name="Subscribe2" TypeName="FzUDP.Subscribe" ProviderName="FzUDP_1" Position="547,107.533530201483" InitPriority="2">
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastIp" Value="224.0.0.0" />
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastPort" Value="61499" />
          <Parameter Name="Decryption" Value="0" />
          <Parameter Name="PacketFormat" Value="0" />
        </Service>
</Services>
```

needs to be transformed into:

```
<ServiceProviders>
<ServiceProvider Name="FzUDP" TypeName="FzUDP">
    <Services>
        <Service Name="Publish" TypeName="Publish" InitPriority="1">
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastIp" Value="224.0.0.0" />
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastPort" Value="61499" />
          <Parameter Name="Encryption" Value="0" />
          <Parameter Name="PacketFormat" Value="0" />
        </Service>
        <Service Name="Subscribe" TypeName="Subscribe" InitPriority="2">
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastIp" Value="224.0.0.0" />
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastPort" Value="61499" />
          <Parameter Name="Decryption" Value="0" />
          <Parameter Name="PacketFormat" Value="0" />
        </Service>
    </Services>
</ServiceProvider>  
<ServiceProvider Name="FzUDP_1" TypeName="FzUDP">
    <Services>
        <Service Name="Subscribe2" TypeName="Subscribe" InitPriority="2">
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastIp" Value="224.0.0.0" />
          <Parameter Name="MultiCastPort" Value="61499" />
          <Parameter Name="Decryption" Value="0" />
          <Parameter Name="PacketFormat" Value="0" />
        </Service>
    </Services>
</ServiceProvider>
```

The xsl code I have come up with so far is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:key name="uniqueProviders" match="Service[@ProviderName]" use="Service[@Name]" />


<xsl:template match="Services">
<ServiceProviders>
  <xsl:for-each select=?>


  </xsl:for-each>


</ServiceProviders>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to use the ProviderName inside the Service element and put them as the key and the Service Name as values. But I am not sure how to use them. Also notice that:

```
a. Attribute Position is not required in the transformed XML.
b. The TypeName attribute of the ServiceProvider element is the first '.' split of the TypeName attribute of the Service element.
```

So I think Service element needs to be created after ServiceProviders, but Parameter element can be probably copied. Where do I go from here?

edit 1: I got the following using XSLT 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
                extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
  xmlns:bootFile="http://tempuri.org/BootfileDefinition"
                xmlns:apps="http://tempuri.org/FZDevice">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match ="//apps:Services">
    <xsl:element name="ServiceProviders">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//apps:Service" group-by="//apps:Service/@ProviderName">
        <xsl:element name="ServiceProvider">
          <xsl:attribute name="Name">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          </xsl:attribute>

          <xsl:attribute name="TypeName">
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(current-group()[1]/@TypeName, '\.')[1]"/>
          </xsl:attribute>

          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:element name="Service">

              <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
              </xsl:attribute>

              <xsl:attribute name="TypeName">
                <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@TypeName, '\.')[2]"/>
              </xsl:attribute>

              <xsl:attribute name="InitPriority">
                <xsl:value-of select="@InitPriority"/>
              </xsl:attribute>

              <xsl:copy-of select="//apps:Parameter"/>

            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each> 

        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that there are namespaces prefixed to the element names. I would get rid of them in the output XML and would appreciate if someone can help me with doing the same thing in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Can you explain in a few words what is the actual problem here? It seems you want to group the services by the `ProviderName` attribute. Why is it necessary to tokenize anything? And why do you need to use Muenchian grouping if you're using XSLT 2.0? And why is `Subscribe2` under `FzUDP_1` in your result? And why do you have a template matching `FourZeroBootFile/Runtime` when there are no such elements in the input?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have fixed the mistakes in the question. So in XSLT 2.0 there is a better way?

Comment: I still don't understand your output. But if what I said is true, then you can simply use use `<xsl:for-each-group select="Service" group-by="@ProviderName">`. There are many examples of such grouping here on SO.

Comment: I did find such examples, but none pertaining to my specific case as there are more modifications than just grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this adjustment of Muenchian Grouping as you do not need an Identity Transform but a rewrite of *Service* template tailored to grouped key. Also, to split `@TypeName` content by period, use the `substring-before` and `substring-after` functions. And it seems you want the `<xsl:key>` to be a concatenation of `@ProviderName` and `@TypeName` (before period part).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="uniqueProviders" match="Service" use="concat(@ProviderName, substring-before(@TypeName, '.'))" />

    <xsl:template match="/Services">
        <ServiceProviders>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Service"/>
        </ServiceProviders>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="Service[generate-id() = generate-id(key('uniqueProviders', concat(@ProviderName, substring-before(@TypeName, '.')))[1])]">
        <ServiceProvider Name="{@ProviderName}" TypeName="{substring-before(@TypeName, '.')}">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('uniqueProviders', concat(@ProviderName, substring-before(@TypeName, '.')))">
                <Service Name="{@Name}" TypeName="{substring-after(@TypeName, '.')}" InitPriority="{@InitPriority}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                </Service>       
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ServiceProvider>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceProviders>
  <ServiceProvider Name="FzUDP" TypeName="FzUDP">
    <Service Name="Publish" TypeName="Publish" InitPriority="1">
      <Parameter Name="MultiCastIp" Value="224.0.0.0" />
      <Parameter Name="MultiCastPort" Value="61499" />
      <Parameter Name="Encryption" Value="0" />
      <Parameter Name="PacketFormat" Value="0" />
    </Service>
  </ServiceProvider>
  <ServiceProvider Name="FzUDP_1" TypeName="FzUDP">
    <Service Name="Subscribe" TypeName="Subscribe" InitPriority="2">
      <Parameter Name="MultiCastIp" Value="224.0.0.0" />
      <Parameter Name="MultiCastPort" Value="61499" />
      <Parameter Name="Decryption" Value="0" />
      <Parameter Name="PacketFormat" Value="0" />
    </Service>
    <Service Name="Subscribe2" TypeName="Subscribe" InitPriority="2">
      <Parameter Name="MultiCastIp" Value="224.0.0.0" />
      <Parameter Name="MultiCastPort" Value="61499" />
      <Parameter Name="Decryption" Value="0" />
      <Parameter Name="PacketFormat" Value="0" />
    </Service>
  </ServiceProvider>
</ServiceProviders>
```